# top (table of processes) package on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, top

When I run `sudo apt install top`, I get `E: Unable to locate package top`

I searched [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) for [top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(software)) package on 32 bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but there is none.

I wonder if it's correct or I'm missing something.

Comment: `top` should already be installed.  You just run `top` from the command line.  Is there something else you are looking for like `htop` or one of the others?

Comment: The top command should already be installed by default on 16.04. Did you try run it? `top` or `sudo top`

Comment: @Terrance @GrannySez `top` is already installed, I wonder why it is not in repo

Comment: I am going to change that to an answer.

Comment: Updated my answer to help show how to determine the package it is installed with.

Comment: TLDR; run `sudo apt install procps`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is probably installed with the `procps` package. It is also common in all *NIX OSes. If you really need to find what it is installed with, install `apt-file` first:

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

If you run a `which` command it will return the folder that it is installed into:

```
$ which top
/usr/bin/top
```

Then do a search like this:

```
apt-file search --regexp '/top$'
```

It will return a list like this:

```
broctl: /usr/share/broctl/scripts/helpers/top
crossfire-maps: /usr/share/games/crossfire/maps/santo_dominion/magara/well/top
crossfire-maps-small: /usr/share/games/crossfire/maps/santo_dominion/magara/well/top
liece: /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/liece/styles/top
lubuntu-extra-sessions: /usr/share/lxpanel/profile/Lubuntu-Nexus7/panels/top
lxpanel: /etc/xdg/lxpanel/two_panels/panels/top
procps: /usr/bin/top
quilt: /usr/share/quilt/top
trn4: /usr/share/doc/trn4/examples/univ/top
trn4: /usr/share/trn4/HelpFiles/top
```

Then all you have to do is match the folder, and that is the package at the beginning of the line.

Or, you could combine the statement as one and it should return a more exact result:

```
$ apt-file search --regexp "^$(which top)$"
procps: /usr/bin/top
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can just use `dpkg -S /usr/bin/top` to find out in which installed package the top binary lives. No need to install `apt-file`.

Comment: @marcelm You could write an answer for that if you want. Your answer would cover the case of finding an already installed package that provides a particular file. Otherwise, one would need to use `apt-file` or https://packages.ubuntu.com.

Comment: `apt-get install procps` is the not-so-front-and-center solution here I was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using http://packages.ubuntu.com/ to find packages that provide `top`, you need to search for `top` in the "Search the contents of packages" section. The results of such a search are:

```
File                                                            Packages
/etc/xdg/lxpanel/two_panels/panels/top                          lxpanel
/usr/bin/top                                                    procps
/usr/share/broctl/scripts/helpers/top                           broctl
/usr/share/doc/trn4/examples/univ/top                           trn4
/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/liece/styles/top                     liece
/usr/share/games/crossfire/maps/santo_dominion/magara/well/top  crossfire-maps, crossfire-maps-small
/usr/share/lxpanel/profile/Lubuntu-Nexus7/panels/top            lubuntu-extra-sessions
/usr/share/quilt/top                                            quilt
/usr/share/trn4/HelpFiles/top                                   trn4
```

In your case, you are most likely looking for the package that provides `/usr/bin/top`, which is `procps`.

Unsurprisingly, the search results are identical to the ones found using `apt-file` as mentioned in @Terrance's answer.